# WiFi network is not working

Tags: installation, wireless

I'm having trouble connecting to WiFi modem. I can connect easily in Windows, but in Ubuntu it can only connect over wired network.

I have a fair knowledge of networking using Windows, but not with Ubuntu.

I do not understand what the issue may be. My WiFi card is compatible with Linux OS.

What should my troubleshooting steps be?

Comment: you said it's WIFI modem. Can you please provide the specification of your modem(name, model number etc)?

Comment: May you don't have driver for you wifi card. while connected to network you just search for additional driver in dash and see if your system is suggesting any driver. If yes then select the driver and click activate. That will automatically download and install the driver. After restarting your wifi should work. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would first check in the dash and type in the box the keyword "additional drivers." This certain tool, will see if you are missing a driver and devices in the system. Especially for My wifi device. Really important check it out. My second advice would be checking out the company that made it, let it be sprint, version, or att. The very last choice would be doing some research for this exact problem. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the system, this has helped me this many wifi related issues. open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will ask for your password, and then it will run the commands. it might ask you to say yes several times, this is permission to install certain updates.

I hope you can resolve your issue!